# Rails - Order issue while using limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, limit

product.rb

```
def self.with_price_nearest_to(price)
  order("abs(products.discount_price - #{price})")
end
```

My main query is

```
results = Product.where("products.category_id = ? AND products.id <  ?", product.category_id, product.id)
                 .with_price_nearest_to(product.discount_price)
```

when i fetch the ids from results it give me below result

```
[3767, 2223, 3766, 3703, 3563, 3562, 3665, 2570, 1915, 3704......]
```

when i add limit in results, like results.limit(10), it give me below result

```
[3766, 2223, 3767, 3665, 2570, 3563, 1915, 3562, 3703, 3667]
```

Both SQL queries are same, in limit there is only `LIMIT 10` added in results.limit(10)

when i do `Product.limit(10).ids`, also get products id in random order.
Can someone explain, is there any issue with limit ? why can't i get a proper order ? i also try to do order after limit but get same result as above

**Update**

I can get the correct order with `results.first(10)`, `results.take(10)`, but i only want results in ActiveRecord, i don't want result in Array, because afterwards i need to do eager loading on results.

Comment: They have the same expression result? ORDER BY does not promise anything about
the ordering of rows with equal keys.

Comment: Results are always different when use limit

Comment: Are they random or look like random? As I've mentioned, results with the same value for `ORDER BY` expression can be returned in different order. Try to add another ORDER BY expression e.g. additional sort by `created_at` or `id`.

Answer (score -1):

It's because of different records. If you are not using `limit(10)` you apply `abs(products.discount_price - #{price})` to all records in table. But then you use limit. You apply that statement only for first 10 records, and order by them. To do what you want you can order w/o limit, convert to array and take first 10 elements. Something like this:

```
Product.where("products.category_id = ? AND products.id <> ? ", product.category_id, product.id)
       .with_price_nearest_to(product.discount_price)
       .to_a.first(10)
```

I think `to_a` can be omitted, but I'm not sure ^_^

But be care, this option is Ok only if you don't need `ActiveRecord` relation as result.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention in question that i need result in ActiveRecord not in array

Comment: If i use limit, after doing order , than also i am getting incorrect order.

Comment: LIMIT executes after ORDER BY.